# Python/Flask: ImportError: Cannot import name 'app' from 'core'

Tags: python, flask, python-import

I have been stuck on this for 3 hours now and the solutions I have looked up on Google haven't helped at all. I am using Flask and my file structure is this:

```
| run.py
|
| core |
     __init__.py
    routes.py
    templates |
             ... (html)
    static |
          ... (js/css)
```

I'm not exactly sure when the error occurred, but here's all my imports (they are listed at the top of each file):

In `run.py`:

```py
from core import app
```

In `__init.py__`:

```py
from core import app, routes
from flask import Flask
from flask_htmlmin import HTMLMIN

from flask_dance.contrib.google import make_google_blueprint
import os
```

In `routes.py`:

```py
from flask import render_template, redirect, url_for, request, abort
from core import app, blueprint
from werkzeug.exceptions import HTTPException

from flask_dance.contrib.google import google
import requests
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hrb7g.png)

Comment: You have a circular import and an import an the same module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to use blueprints. It makes your application modular and easy to work with. Check the docs here [Modular applications with Blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/blueprints/)
Altogether, you can have your application working with this setup:
Folder structure:

`├──|core
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── routes.py
│   ├── static
│   └── templates
├── run.py
└── venv`

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from .routes import main
from flask_htmlmin import HTMLMIN 

from flask_dance.contrib.google import make_google_blueprint
import os

def create_app(config_obj=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_obj)

    # register the blueprints
    app.register_blueprint(main)

    return app
```

run.py

```
from core import create_app

class Config:
    DEBUG = True

app = create_app(Config)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

routes.py

```
from flask import Blueprint

main = Blueprint('main', __name__)

@main.route('/')
def index():
    return 'My awesome index page!'
```

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this